# Unable to choose functions for evaluating a limit using the Squeeze Theorem

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, central-limit-theorem

> Evaluate $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+...+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n}}$$

$$$$
I'm supposed to solve this problem using the Squeeze Theorem. I had selected the functions:$$$$$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}\le \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+...+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n}}\le \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}+...+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n+1}}$$

$$$$I know that these functions that I had selected are wrong because they are strictly less than or strictly more than the given function in the limit. I can't understand what functions to choose which would maintain the $\le$ sign.
$$$$
Could somebody please show me what functions to select instead? Many thanks!

Comment: Why not replace $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}}$ by $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: Sir please could you explain the intuition/motivation behind the substitution you suggested?

Comment: Motivation: you want something that is easy to add up, and which does not distort the value too much. For large $n$ we have $2n+1$ terms each roughly $\frac{1}{n}$ so we expect the limit to be 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sum $S(n)$ has

$$\frac{2n+1}{n+1} \leq S(n) \leq \frac{2n+1}{n}$$

Can you see why?

Hint: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}} \leq \frac{1}{n}$ when $0 \leq k \leq 2n$.

Hint 2: $n^2+k \leq n^2+2n$ (for $k \leq 2n$)

Hence $ n^2+k < n^2+2n+1 = (n+1)^2$. Hence $\sqrt{n^2+k} \leq n+1$.

Hint 3: There are $2n+1$ terms.

Taking the limit gives

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}S(n)=2$$

Comment: Sorry Sir, but I couldn't understand why the functions you picked satisfy the inequality. could you please explain why you chose them?

Comment: @user342433 I've added another hint.

Comment: Thanks Sir. By fitting examples, I could verify the inequality. But could you please show me how I might prove them?

Comment: @user342433 does that help?

Comment: $n^{2}+k\geq n^{2}$ for any $k\geq 0$, hence $\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^{2}+k}} \le \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^{2}}}=\tfrac{1}{n}$ since $n\geq 1$. On the other hand, as $k\le 2n$, we have $n^{2}+k\le n^{2}+2n\le n^{2}+2n+1 = (n+1)^{2}$ and as previously, you deduce $\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{n^{2}+k}}\geq \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)^{2}}}=\tfrac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer Thank you Sir, I understood the set of inequalities $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}} \leq \frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: @Shakespeare Thanks, it did help. Lastly, could you please explain why you picked $2n+1$ in the numerator?

Comment: @user342433 I just added a final hint. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: Sir, I know that there are $2n+1$ terms. I'm sorry but I still don't understand its significance due to which you kept it in the numerator. Sorry for all these doubts, but this is the first time I'm doing the Squeeze theorem and am quite confused.$$$$PS. Sir, obviously I will accept the answer once I understand everything.

Comment: So you have $2n+1$ terms to each of which the inequality above applies (which you have now understood). Hence the total sum $S(n)$ is at most $2n+1$ amounts of $1/n$ and at least $2n+1$ amounts of $1/n$.

Comment: @user342433 another way of putting it is $S(n) \geq 1/n+1/n+1/n+...+1/n$, where there are $2n+1$ terms, so $S(n) \geq 2n+1/n$

Comment: Alright Sir, thanks a lot!